# How to name the marker size in scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently, I used the following program (which has no particular interest, other than personal...):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6,3))

N = 100
mu = [4,3]
cov = [[0.25,0.50],[0.50, 2.50]]

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed = 1949)
draw = partial(pm.draw, random_seed = rng)

x_draws = draw(pm.MvNormal.dist(mu = mu, cov = cov), draws = N)

ax.scatter(x_draws[:, 0], 
           x_draws[:, 1], 
           color = "darkblue", 
           markersize = 5,
           alpha = 1)

plt.show()
```

If you run it, you'll get an error:

```
PathCollection.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markersize'
```

It means that I can use `c =` **or** `color =` for specifying the color, but I absolutely need to use `s =` **and not** `markersize =` for specifying the size of the marker...?

Isn't that inconsistent?

Can I replace `s =` with another denomination if I want to? Or do I have to stay "stuck" to `s =` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is inconsistent, but that's just how it is. The [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) function takes an optional argument `c`, but you can also pass additional `kwargs` that are interpreted by [`matplotlib.collections.set`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection). Looking at the documentation for that, there is a `color` optional `kwarg`, but no `markersize`, which is why you can't use it. On the other hand, the [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) function has a `markersize` or `ms` optional kwarg, which is why you can use it there.

Comment: well okay, then! we have to admit that developers don't always think of harmonizing everything...

Comment: @Andrew Maybe there's a reason it is this way, but I don't know what that reason might be.